# Stop reactor in Twisted.internet after a condition

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted, twisted.internet

I have a simple code in which I am testing how Twisted.internet module is working.
I am trying to stop the loop when a certain condition occurs (e.g: when i equals to 5), but I couldn't get it run.
I have two main errors:

**1.**

```
exceptions.UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment
```

**2.**
In case I just add **reactor.stop()** at the end without the If Statement, the loop doesn't stop, why ?

```
from twisted.internet import task
from twisted.internet import reactor

time = 1.0 # one seconds
i=0
def myfunction():
    print "sth"
    i +=1
    pass

l = task.LoopingCall(myfunction)
l.start(timeout) # call every second
reactor.run()
if i==5:
    reactor.stop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `i` should be declared as a global variable.

   `i += 1` is equivalent to `i = i + 1`. If you don't declare it as a global variable, it is regarded as a local variable. The right part of the assignment tried to access the undefined local variable; cause of the `UnboundLocalError`.
2. The `if` statement will never executed until the event loop stop. You need to put it inside the callback function.

---

```
from twisted.internet import task
from twisted.internet import reactor

time = 1.0 # one seconds
i = 0
def myfunction():
    global i
    print "sth"
    i += 1
    if i == 5:
        reactor.stop()

timeout = 0.1
l = task.LoopingCall(myfunction)
l.start(timeout) # call every second
reactor.run()
```